# Big O notation for non nested loops

Tags: big-o

I have a question in regards to big-o-notation. when you have 2 non-nested loop in a function:1st with the runtime O(N^2), 2ND: with runtime O(N). what will be the run-time of that function? I think it's O(N^2)

Part of my project is to right the run-time for the functions stated in the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxt_6d1O-eKnWmdfejMzUjdXelE/view?usp=sharing

I have wrote the run-time for the scenario. If anyone can double check the run-time for me please.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxt_6d1O-eKncHo4c0dSdnMtUWc/view?usp=sharing

thanks

Comment: If you have code that does Thing A in time O(n) and then Thing B in time O(n^2), the runtime would be O(n + n^2) = O(n^2). Also, can you post the relevant code here in the body of the question itself rather than using external links?

Answer (score 0):

When you have something that happens after something else, you sum their complexity time. And the leading complexity time is the winner there. so:

```
O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n^2 + n) = O(n^2)
```

If you had a loop in the loop you would then multiply them: `O(n^2 * n) = O(n^3)`.